# Два раза выполняется запрос к БД

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Хочу отправить через AJAX запрос к серверу на добавление строки в бд.
Но почему-то отправляется 2 запроса к серверу и в БД добавляется 2 одинаковых строки. Хотя в PHP я нигде не ссылаюсь 2-жды на один файл.

```
function add(
    $sku = NULL,
    $name = NULL,
    $price = NULL,
    $type = NULL,
    $size = NULL,
    $height = NULL,
    $width = NULL,
    $length = NULL,
    $weight = NULL)
{
     $conn = $this->database->connect();
     $sql->bind_param('ssisiiiii', $sku, $name, $price, $type, $size, $height, $width, $length, $weight);
     $sql->execute();
     

}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#form").submit(function (e) { // Устанавливаем событие отправки для формы с id=form
        var form_data = $(this).serialize(); // Собираем все данные из формы
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", // Метод отправки
            cache: false,
           // url: ".addproduct.php", // Путь до php файла отправителя
            data: form_data,
            success: function () {
                // Код в этом блоке выполняется при успешной отправке сообщения
                alert("Ваше bggg отправлено!");
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<form method="post" action="addproduct.php" id="form">
    <div class="row" style="height: 15vh;">
        <div class="col d-flex d-sm-flex d-md-flex justify-content-end align-items-end align-content-end flex-wrap justify-content-sm-center align-items-sm-center justify-content-md-center align-items-md-center">
            <h1>Product list</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col d-flex d-lg-flex flex-row justify-content-end align-items-end align-content-end flex-wrap justify-content-lg-center align-items-lg-center"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="margin-right: 30px;">Save</button><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href = '../'"  type="button">Cancle</button></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Посмотрите в консоле браузера, сколько запросов отправляется на сервер и какие у них заголовки.
e.preventDefault() у вас вызывается поздновато похоже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.preventDefault();` надо ставить не внутри `success`, а перед отправкой, например перед строкой `var form_data = $(this).serialize();`. Обычно эту строку пишут сразу же в начале функции, чтобы не париться

Comment: Спасибо. Да, теперь работает правильно.

Comment: Двойной запрос из-за этого разве? Я просто обычно это пишу, чтобы страничка не обновлялась, но ни разу не использовал это чтобы предотвратить несколько запросов

Comment: @EzioMercer один из-за ajax, второй - из-за несработающего preventDefault и перезагрузка формы

Comment: @Him4enko отметье ответ как Принятый пожалуйста, если он вам помог

Comment: Не понял, как второй раз идёт этот же запрос из-за того что не сработал `e.preventDefault`?

Comment: @EzioMercer срабатывает обычный сабмит формы.

Comment: @u_mulder "Срабатывает" - кто его вызывает? Само упоминание `e` или что-то другое?

Comment: Нажатие `button type=submit`

Comment: @u_mulder А разве тогда не вызывается как раз `submit` формы, который слушается? Или имеете ввиду, что событие `click` по кнопке ещё раз вызывает `submit`?

Comment: @EzioMercer `$("#form").submit` вызывает сабмит формы.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Можно пожалуйста чуть подробнее, а то вы оба пишите короткими ответами, а я не могу уловить суть :) Первый раз вызывается из-за того что нажали на `button type=submit` и вызывается событие `submit` у формы, а второй раз, кто конкретно вызывает это же событие?

Comment: @EzioMercer никакой кнопки submit тут нет. Первый раз `$("#form").submit` вызывает сабмит формы, а второй запрос - ajax запрос, который написан в колбэке

Comment: @АлексейШиманский кнопка вообще-то есть в разметке.

Comment: @EzioMercer не заметил......ну вот она да, вызывает один из вызовов, и второй - ajax

Comment: @u_mulder Всё, понял. Всем спасибо :)